# Pasar código C# a Visual Basic

Tags: c#, vb.net

Deseo pasar el siguiente código a visual basic, el código permite redimensionar ventanas por favor alguien podria ayudarme de antemano gracias.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message msj)
        {
            const int CoordenadaWFP = 0x84; 
            const int DesIzquierda = 16;
            const int DesDerecha = 17;
            if (msj.Msg == CoordenadaWFP)
            {
                int x = (int)(msj.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF);
                int y = (int)((msj.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
                Point CoordenadaArea = PointToClient(new Point(x, y));
                Size TamañoAreaForm = ClientSize;
                if (CoordenadaArea.X >= TamañoAreaForm.Width - 16 && CoordenadaArea.Y >= TamañoAreaForm.Height - 16 && TamañoAreaForm.Height >= 16)
                {
                    msj.Result = (IntPtr)(IsMirrored ? DesIzquierda : DesDerecha);
                    return;
                }
            }
            base.WndProc(ref msj);
        }
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema que tuviste?

Comment: deseo tenerlo pero en visual basic

Comment: Te entiendo eso, pero cual es el problema que tuviste al tratar de pasarlo? hay herramientas on line que te ayudan, y tambien lo podes hacer a mano. Tuviste algun problema particular al tratar de hacerlo?

Comment: si lo que pasa es que desconozco C# apenas voy empezando a programar y utilice una pagina que se llama code converter pero el codigo que me da me marca errores y ademas me da muchas lineas de código como si fueran comentarios. lo que necesito es si alguien podria pasarmelo a visual basic

Comment: Tal vez, ya que estas tratando de aprender, primero deberias comentar que se supone que hace este codigo, y despues mostrar lo que tenes en VB, y depurar ese codigo con lo que hayas intentado y explicando lo que entiendas de ese codigo.

Comment: Puedes compilar el C# hasta un DLL y dar una referencia a él en VB.

Comment: Si apenas estas aprendiendo a programar no deberias de meterte a usar la API de Windows, primero empieza desde lo basico con esa API. Pero si lo vas a intentar aqui hay algunos ejemplos basicos del uso de la API: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.showwindow)

Comment: ok amigo muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui lo tienes, no es excesivamente complicado:
............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef msj As Message)
    Const CoordenadaWFP As Integer = &H84
    Const DesIzquierda As Integer = 16
    Const DesDerecha As Integer = 17

    If msj.Msg = CoordenadaWFP Then
        Dim x As Integer = CInt((msj.LParam.ToInt64() And &HFFFF))
        Dim y as Integer = CInt((msj.LParam.ToInt64() & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16)
        Dim CoordenadaArea As Point = PointToClient(New Point(x, y))
        Dim TamañoAreaForm As Size = ClientSize

        If CoordenadaArea.X >= TamañoAreaForm.Width - 16 AndAlso CoordenadaArea.Y >= TamañoAreaForm.Height - 16 AndAlso TamañoAreaForm.Height >= 16 Then
            msj.Result = CType((If(IsMirrored, DesIzquierda, DesDerecha)), IntPtr)
            Return
        End If
    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(msj)
End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias valentin excelente.